# MVC Core and IdentityServer3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver3

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to use .NET Core 1.1 with IdentityServer3. I have my own IdentityServer3 instance running at my company. The IdentityServer3 libraries I pull out of Nuget do not work with .NET Core 1.1 and it appears that I can only use the IdentityServer4 packages from Nuget.

I've tried looking for examples or discussions, but they I'm having a really difficult time finding this information. How do I get my new core app connected to my IdentityServer3 server?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the [client samples in the Identity Server 4 repository](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Clients). You should be able to use those clients with an IdentityServer3 instance.

Comment: Interesting, so I can use IdentityServer4 dlls to connect to IdentityServer3? I couldn't find any information out there on whether that would actually work. I'll start by trying those examples. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, we are doing this successfully. Specifically, we were able to use the MvcImplicit example client with our Identity Server 3. I believe the other clients would work as well. You should also be able to [use the newer Access Token Validation middleware with Identity Server 3](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation/issues/17). OpenID Connect FTW :)

Comment: Thanks Rob, I appreciate your help!